Livekit await room.connect takes more than 4s to connect
I am creating a one to one video calling app using flutter_webrtc and Livekit. And I have:
await room.connect(
          url,
          token,
          fastConnectOptions: FastConnectOptions(
            microphone: TrackOption(track: _audioTrack),
            camera: TrackOption(track: _videoTrack),
          ),
        );
    

to connect to the room. But this takes more than 4s on average to connect. How can I reduce this time to 1-2s? I have tried removing the fast connection option or setting them to null, but still get the same time to connect. Could someone please help me with this?
